# How to simplify this 3 switch-case functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement, case, simplify

I want to simplify this long jquery/javascript code, can you help me? I still learn :)

Here's my jquery code:

```
$('.pagination-link').click(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    currentAnchor = $('body').attr('class');
    switch (currentAnchor) {
      case 'active-slide-1':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond1').animate();
        break;
      case 'active-slide-2':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond2').animate();
        break;
      case 'active-slide-3':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond3').animate();
        break;
      case 'active-slide-4':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond4').animate();
        break;
      case 'active-slide-5':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond5').animate();
        break;
      case 'active-slide-6':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond6').animate();
        break;
      case 'active-slide-7':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond7').animate();
        break;
      case 'active-slide-8':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond8').animate();
        break;
      default:
        $('#rond').removeClass();
    }
  }, 50);
});

$('.overlay-menu > ul > li > a').click(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    currentAnchor = $('body').attr('class');
    switch (currentAnchor) {
      case 'active-slide-1':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond1').animate();
        break;
      case 'active-slide-2':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond2').animate();
        break;
      case 'active-slide-3':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond3').animate();
        break;
      case 'active-slide-4':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond4').animate();
        break;
      case 'active-slide-5':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond5').animate();
        break;
      case 'active-slide-6':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond6').animate();
        break;
      case 'active-slide-7':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond7').animate();
        break;
      case 'active-slide-8':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond8').animate();
        break;
      default:
        $('#rond').removeClass();
    }
  }, 50);
});

$(window).mousewheel(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    currentAnchor = $('body').attr('class');
    switch (currentAnchor) {
      case 'active-slide-1':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond1').animate();
        break;
      case 'active-slide-2':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond2').animate();
        break;
      case 'active-slide-3':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond3').animate();
        break;
      case 'active-slide-4':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond4').animate();
        break;
      case 'active-slide-5':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond5').animate();
        break;
      case 'active-slide-6':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond6').animate();
        break;
      case 'active-slide-7':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond7').animate();
        break;
      case 'active-slide-8':
        $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond8').animate();
        break;
      default:
        $('#rond').removeClass();
    }
  }, 50);
});
```

I don't know if I have to use php to get the end of currentAnchor and put it as a parameters.  Thank you for your help !

EDIT: I found that the default case is not necessary in my code. But I learn something new if I had my defaut case was important. So, here it's the new one:

```
            function rondClass() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    currentAnchor = $('body').attr('class'); 
                    var currentClass = currentAnchor.replace('active-slide-', 'rond');
                    $('#rond').removeClass().addClass(currentClass).animate();
                }, 50);
            }


            $('.pagination-link').click(rondClass);
            $('.overlay-menu > ul > li > a').click(rondClass);
            $(window).mousewheel(rondClass);
```

Thank you everyone !

Answer (score 2):

You could just replace `active-slide-` with `rond`.

```
var currentAnchor = $('body').attr('class');
var newClass = currentAnchor.replace('active-slide-', 'rond');
$('#rond').removeClass().addClass(newClass).animate();
```

To handle the default case, you can handle this using [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) or [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
// indexOf version
if (currentAnchor.indexOf('active-slide-') !== 0) {
  $('#rond').removeClass();
} else {
  $('#rond').removeClass().addClass(newClass).animate();
}

// match version
if (!currentAnchor.match(/^active-slide-/)) {
  $('#rond').removeClass();
} else {
  $('#rond').removeClass().addClass(newClass).animate();
}
```

Comment: Only one thing to add, is that it doesn't implement the `default` block. A match to a regex like `if(currentAnchor.match(/active-slide-\d/) {..} else {..}` is probably needed to prevent adding a class that isn't of that pattern.

Comment: What if the class is "active-class-a_string_which_is_not_a_number_between_1_and_8_or_no_string_at_all" ?

Comment: @loxaxs Then I think they need to organize their classes better ;)

Comment: This problem is adressed by adding the tests `len == 14` and `49 <= char && char <= 56`, with `len` and `char` set to: `len = currentAnchor.length` and `char = currentAnchor.charCodeAt(len-1)`. (49 is the char code for "1", and 56 the one for "8")

Answer (score 1):

Replace switch/case with programmatic approach and extract function to avoid code duplication.

```
var onClick = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    currentAnchor = $('body').attr('class'); 
    var slide = currentAnchor.match(/active\-slide\-(\d)/);
    if (slide) {
      $('#rond').removeClass().addClass('rond' + slide[1]).animate();
    } else {
      $('#rond').removeClass();
    }
  }, 50)
})

$('.overlay-menu > ul > li > a').click(onClick);
$('.pagination-link').click(onClick);
```

Comment: Is it possible to make one function for each case?
I tried but no working:


function rondclass() {
//myfunction
}

$('.pagination-link').click(function rondclass());
$('.overlay-menu > ul > li > a').click(function rondclass());
$(window).mousewheel(function rondclass());

Comment: @PauleAnne To pass a function as a parameter, just give its name without any parentheses. So it would be `$(window).mousewheel(rondclass);` for example.

Comment: Yes it is possible and recommended to reuse functions whenever possible.

Comment: @4castle Thank you !!